# XSLT - How can I generate input to output mapping if I only have XSLT with me?

Tags: mapping, xslt-2.0

So, we have a XSLT that is maintained by our team. The requirement is to generate input to output logic mapping by parsing/utilizing that XSLT. This is required so that we do not have to maintain a mapping manually.

I need some inputs on how this can be done. Is there a software already available? Do I write my own program? How should I approach this?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I don't think there is a general solution to this, an XSLT stylesheet is a program that can create any output. So unless you know the XSLT is simple and follows a strict and simple approach like e.g. `<xsl:template match="foo"><bar><xsl:apply-templates/></bar></xsl:template>` there is no way to simply analyze programmatically what an XSLT program does.  What format do you expect that mapping to have?

Comment: Hmm...that's what I thought. CSV would do. Input xpath, output xpath, logic if any.